# how to remove a category from woocommerce products through instantsearch js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, algolia, instantsearch

I've tried it that way but not working, i think it must have some specific way to call the woocommerce category

```
    search = instantsearch({
      appId: 'myid',
      apiKey: 'mykey',
      indexName: 'wp_posts_product',
      searchParameters: {
        filters: filters,
        hitsPerPage: 9,
            facetsExcludes: {
                categories: ['Destaques', 'destaques']
            }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter out a specific category, you need to leverage the `filters` parameter of the Algolia API.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/?language=javascript#combination-of-filters

If I adjust your code, it would give you something like:

```
var search = instantsearch({
  appId: "myid",
  apiKey: "mykey",
  indexName: "wp_posts_product",
  searchParameters: {
    filters: "NOT categories:Destaques",
    hitsPerPage: 9,
  }
});
```

Note that Algolia computes facet values in a case insensitive fashion.
As a result you do not need to also specify: `NOT categories:Destaques`.

If your category contains spaces, ensure you wrap it in double quotes like so: `NOT categories:"Destaques"`.

Finally you want to exclude multiple categories, you can combine conditions with the `AND` statement: `NOT categories:Destaques AND NOT categories:"other with spaces"`.